# I want to get rid of using one table by adding code as a subselect to the UNION

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have this working Union

```
INSERT INTO [Transform].PosSalesUnion 
         (DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber, poolID)


SELECT poolID, DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber 
FROM [Transform].Devices_DeviceGroups_PosSales
  
UNION

SELECT NULL, DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber 
FROM [Transform].PosSalesNotMatch
```

As you can see I read from table [Transform].PosSalesNotMatch. Now I hope to minimize the usage of separate tables and instead add the code that populate this table [Transform].PosSalesNotMatch.

The code that populate this table [Transform].PosSalesNotMatch is this code

```
INSERT INTO [Transform].PosSalesNotMatch
   SELECT a.DeviceId, a.DayClosureId, a.TransactionId, a.IndetId, a.TicketId,a.CategoryId,a.ArticleId,a.CurrencyId,a.Datetime,a.IsSuccessful,a.Quantity,a.Turnover,a.TurnoverTarget,a.SalesTransactionTypeId,a.ValidFrom,a.ValidTo,a.SerialNumber
   from [Transform].PosSales a
   left join [Transform].Devices_DeviceGroups b on a.DeviceId = b.DeviceId
   where b.DeviceId is null
```

Now I have tried to add this code as a subselect to the union but I get syntax error. The final code that I have tried is this

```
 INSERT INTO [Transform].PosSalesUnion 
         (DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber, poolID)
 

 SELECT poolID, DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber 
 FROM [Transform].Devices_DeviceGroups_PosSales

   UNION

 SELECT NULL, DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber 

   (SELECT a.DeviceId, a.DayClosureId, a.TransactionId, a.IndetId, a.TicketId,a.CategoryId,a.ArticleId,a.CurrencyId,a.Datetime,a.IsSuccessful,a.Quantity,a.Turnover,a.TurnoverTarget,a.SalesTransactionTypeId,a.ValidFrom,a.ValidTo,a.SerialNumber
   from [Transform].PosSales a
 left join [Transform].Devices_DeviceGroups b on a.DeviceId = b.DeviceId
   where b.DeviceId is null)
```

Comment: The formatting is horrible -- and it would help you too since you can see that the code you show with a syntax error is clearly missing a from statement.  -- you have the select but no from keyword -- did you want to say from that sub-select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is you did not have the FROM keyword.  On SQL Server you also have to give an alias to sub-queries.

```
 INSERT INTO [Transform].PosSalesUnion 
         (DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber, poolID)
 

   SELECT poolID, DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber 
   FROM [Transform].Devices_DeviceGroups_PosSales

     UNION

   SELECT NULL, DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber 
   FROM 
     (SELECT a.DeviceId, a.DayClosureId, a.TransactionId, a.IndetId, a.TicketId,a.CategoryId,a.ArticleId,a.CurrencyId,a.Datetime,a.IsSuccessful,a.Quantity,a.Turnover,a.TurnoverTarget,a.SalesTransactionTypeId,a.ValidFrom,a.ValidTo,a.SerialNumber
      from [Transform].PosSales a
      left join [Transform].Devices_DeviceGroups b on a.DeviceId = b.DeviceId
      where b.DeviceId is null
     ) as X
```

After looking at it formatted well I can see you don't need the sub-query

```
 INSERT INTO [Transform].PosSalesUnion 
         (DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber, poolID)
 

   SELECT poolID, DeviceId, DayClosureId, TransactionId, IndetId, TicketId, CategoryId, ArticleId, CurrencyId, Datetime, IsSuccessful, Quantity, Turnover, TurnoverTarget, SalesTransactionTypeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo, SerialNumber 
   FROM [Transform].Devices_DeviceGroups_PosSales

     UNION

   SELECT NULL, a.DeviceId, a.DayClosureId, a.TransactionId, a.IndetId, a.TicketId,a.CategoryId,a.ArticleId,a.CurrencyId,a.Datetime,a.IsSuccessful,a.Quantity,a.Turnover,a.TurnoverTarget,a.SalesTransactionTypeId,a.ValidFrom,a.ValidTo,a.SerialNumber
   FROM [Transform].PosSales a
   LEFT JOIN [Transform].Devices_DeviceGroups b on a.DeviceId = b.DeviceId
   WHERE b.DeviceId is null
```